# pivot query on multiple columns

Tags: sql

I want to write a pivot query in the table below.
essentially I want the output to look like this

```
col1 col2       HDL  LDL CDL MDL
111  2018-12-21 110  23  21  212
111  2018-12-22 212  4312    21
... and so on
```

the col 1 and col 2 combined is unique

```
col1 col2       col3 col4
111 2018-12-21  HDL 110
111 2018-12-21  LDL 23
111 2018-12-21  CDL 21
111 2018-12-21  MDL 212

111 2018-12-22  MDL 21
111 2018-12-22  HDL 212
111 2018-12-22  LDL 4312

333 2018-12-22  HDL 112
444 2018-12-22  PPP 00112
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select col1, col2, 
       max(case when col3 = 'HDL' then col4 end) as HDL,
       max(case when col3 = 'LDL' then col4 end) as LDL,
       max(case when col3 = 'CDL' then col4 end) as CDL,
       max(case when col3 = 'MDL' then col4 end) as MDL
from t
group by col1, col2;
```

Comment: Is there a way to mark the question as answered. I can't seem to find it.